# How to get LibreOffice headless Calc calculate to save new values from uno?

Tags: python, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, uno

I am trying to open an excel file from python, get it to recalculate and then save it with the newly calculated values.
The spreadsheet is large and opens fine in LibreOffice with GUI, and initially shows old values.  If I then do a Data->Calculate->Recalculate Hard I see the correct values, and I can of course saveas and all seems fine.
But, there are multiple large spreadsheets I want to do it from so I don't want to use a GUI instead I want to use Python.  The following all seems to work to create a new spreadsheet but it doesn't have the new values (unless I again manually do a recalculate hard)

I'm running on Linux.  First I do this:

```
soffice  --headless --nologo --nofirststartwizard --accept="socket,host=0.0.0.0,port=8100,tcpNoDelay=1;urp"
```

Then, here is sample python code:

```
import uno

local = uno.getComponentContext()
resolver = local.ServiceManager.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.bridge.UnoUrlResolver", local)
context = resolver.resolve("uno:socket,host=localhost,port=8100;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager")
remoteContext = context.getPropertyValue("DefaultContext")
desktop = context.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", remoteContext)
document = desktop.getCurrentComponent()


file_url="file://foo.xlsx"
document = desktop.loadComponentFromURL(file_url, "_blank", 0, ())

controller=document.getCurrentController()

sheet=document.getSheets().getByIndex(0)
controller.setActiveSheet(sheet)
document.calculateAll()

file__out_url="file://foo_out.xlsx"
from com.sun.star.beans import PropertyValue
pv_filtername = PropertyValue()                                             
pv_filtername.Name = "FilterName"                                           
pv_filtername.Value = "Calc MS Excel 2007 XML"                                             

document.storeAsURL(file__out_url, (pv_filtername,))
document.dispose()
```

After running the above code, and opening foo_out.xlsx it shows the "old" values, not the recalculated values.  I know that the calculateAll() is taking a little while, as I would expect for it to do the recalculation.  But, the new values don't seem to actually get saved.
If I open it in Excel it does an auto-recalculate and shows the correct values and if I open in LibreOffice and do Recalculate Hard it shows the correct values. But, what I need is to save it, from python like above, so that it already contains the recalculated values.

Is there any way to do that?

Essentially, what I want to do from python is:
open, recalculate hard, saveas

Comment: One approach, suggested in the AOO forum, would involve using `Copy` and `Paste Special` to replace formulas with calculated values. You'd have to work out the UNO details, of course. [|Solved| Replace formula with value calculated](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=28242)

Comment: That seems like a solution to getting rid of formulas.  I don't want to do that.  I just want to also have the current value stored, so that I don't have to recalculate.  And, so the spreadsheet can be read with pandas.  Currently, pandas just reads in the "old" values.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this was a problem with an older version of LibreOffice.  I was using 5.0.6.2, on Linux, and even though I was recalculating, the new values were not even showing up when I extracted the cell values directly.
However, I upgraded to 6.2 and the problem has gone away, using the same code and the same input files.
I decided to just answer my own question, instead of deleting it, as this was leading to a frustration until I solved it.